# Adding association (link table record) without creating a new related record.

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have two tables Products and Categories with a many to many relationship.  I am trying to copy the categories linked to one product (OriginalProduct) to another product (newProduct).  The problem is when I execute the `SaveChanges()` method, I not only get the records in my linking table, but it also creates another copy of the categories in the categories table. I've tried this in many ways but here are the last couple that I've attempted:

```
 ' Copy Product/Categories
For Each oneProdCategory In OriginalProduct.Categories
  Dim relatedCategory = _productContext.GetObjectByKey(New EntityKey  ("ProductInfoEntities.Categories", "RecordId", oneProdCategory.RecordId))            
  Dim newCategory As New Category

  With newCategory
    .Description = relatedCategory.Description
    .isActive = relatedCategory.IsActive
    .RecordId = relatedCategory.RecordId
  End With

  newProduct.Categories.Add(newCategory)

Next
```

This attempt results in both linking table records being created (which is good) but is also creates copies of all the categories as well (not so good)

```
' Copy Product/Categories
For Each oneProdCategory In OriginalProduct.Categories
  Dim relatedCategory = _productContext.GetObjectByKey(New EntityKey ("ProductInfoEntities.Categories", "RecordId", oneProdCategory.RecordId))

  newProduct.Categories.Add(relatedCategory)

Next
```

This results in the following error:

> "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker."

**Edit**

```
For Each oneProdCategory In OriginalProduct.Categories

  newProduct.Categories.Add(oneProdCategory)

Next


Private Sub tsBtnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsBtnSave.Click 

   _productContext.SaveChanges()

   If _formMode = DataFormAction.Insert Or _formMode = DataFormAction.Duplicate Then
       Me.Close()         
   End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
newProduct.Categories.AddRange(OriginalProduct.Categories)
```

If your  `Categories` property is a `List`
OR

```
For Each oneProdCategory In OriginalProduct.Categories

  newProduct.Categories.Add(oneProdCategory)

Next
```

Make sure all the entities are retrieved, created with the same context.

Comment: Thanks !!   Man was I ever trying to over-complicate this one?!?

Comment: OK, this does get me a step farther, however.  When my code reaches the "SaveChanges" method, I get an error that "Accept changes cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager."  I'm sure this is because the newProduct's allergens are the 'same' as the originalProduct's.  This should be a simple thing, I just need the linking records created.!??

Comment: @RickBen you may have assigned the `OriginalProduct` Id to the `newProduct` id.

Comment: No, I have the newProduct getting a unique ProductId (which is a user supplied id) and the entity is correctly generating a unique RecordId (which is the record's primary key)

Comment: @RickBen can you post the relevant code preferably after the above changes?

Comment: Thanks to the original suggestion I'm now doing the following:

Comment: For Each oneProdCategory In OriginalProduct.Categories

            newProduct.Categories.Add(oneProdCategory)

        Next

Comment: The above snippet works as far as the updates to the database go.  The after these changes, where the error is thrown:    Private Sub tsBtnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsBtnSave.Click

        _productContext.SaveChanges()

        If _formMode = DataFormAction.Insert Or _formMode = DataFormAction.Duplicate Then
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: Sorry for the messy posting.  I'm new to this site.  Is there a cleaner way to post comments & code.  I can't even add a CrLf between my comments and the code I'm posting....??

Comment: @RickBen you can edit your question. when you post code make sure you format it(select the code block and click {}). can you show code segments before and after the `For Each` loop?